# ISO not booting from WD My Passport Ultra

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

I formatted a WD My Passport ultra to NTFS. I checked using PowerISO that the .iso image is indeed bootable. When I plug it in to my Lenovo Laptop I press F12 to bring up the boot options and choose the WD drive. After doing so it tries for a split-second and reloads the menu.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your description is missing a step. How did you put the ISO image on the drive?

Comment: He obviously simply copied it onto the drive... Which is why it's not doing anything

Comment: Which OS is in the ISO, is it a bootable/live OS?

Comment: @YisroelTech That's correct. I thought that would be sufficient. It is a bootable/live OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the iso image to the external HDD using a tool like [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/).

Before using Rufus, be sure to backup everything that is on your external drive. **Once you start imaging your drive with RUFUS, IT WILL DELETE EVERYTHING ON THE DEVICE.**

1. Select your external HDD DEVICE
2. Select this ISO image
3. Start copying the ISO image to your external HDD (**Again, this will delete everything currently on the external drive**)

   [image: enter code here]

---

If this solves your problem, mark this solution as an answer. If it does not solve your problem, please comment why it did not solve your problem and provide additional details about your problem.